# Paypal donation form

Tags: html, forms, paypal

I'm trying to make a custom Paypal donation form for my website where people could choose between 3 options. The first two options have a variable quantity, which would also change the total amount of money that would be donated. In this case, each 'item' would cost $1 (with the exception of Option 3).

Now is my problem, when I would choose 5 cookies for example, it would only charge $1 (because the Waffles are still stuck on 1) instead of $5.

Any thoughts on how to achieve choosing different quanitities without both values inflicting?

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input name="item_number" type="text" placeholder="Your name here" required>
    <br>
    <br><input type="radio" name="amount" value="0.00" required><select name="amount"><option value="1.00">1 Cookie</option><option value="2.00">2 Cookies</option><option value="3.00">3 Cookies</option><option value="4.00">4 Cookies</option><option value="5.00">5 Cookies</option></select> Cookies
    <br><input type="radio" name="amount" value="0.00" required><select name="amount"><option value="1.00">1 Waffle</option><option value="2.00">2 Waffles</option><option value="3.00">3 Waffles</option><option value="4.00">4 Waffles</option><option value="5.00">5 Waffles</option></select> Waffles
    <br><input type="radio" name="amount" value="30.00" required> Option 3
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_donations">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Donation test">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-DonationsBF:btn_donateCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/tr_TR/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    <p><input type="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" value="Confirm" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In any PayPal button, only one drop-down menu option selection can have priced options.
As a workaround you can use Javascript to dynamically get the selected option price and send it to `amount` variable